# Two (or more) Search Activities

Tags: android, search, android-activity

Quick question, is there a way to have two searchable activities?  My search logic is different in two instances inside my app; both from a domain logic (what I am searching) and how I'm presenting the query results.

I'm not sure how to tell my search widget which searchable activity should be used.  Is this possible?

Thanks!